# Azure Data Factory Aggregate count()

Tags: azure-data-factory

i have a query with multiple joins and there is a field that is created from a count, like this:

```
select
t1.clientID,
t1.clientName,
t2.invoiceNo
(select count (*) from invoices where clientID = t1.clientID) AS clientswithSale
from customers t1
JOIN invoices t2 on t2.clientID = t1.clientID
```

how can i create that column using an aggregate transformation inside a data flow with multiple sources?

can i link a source into the count() function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SQL statement in ADF Data Flow would equate to:

Source (Invoices), Source (Customers), Inner Join, Aggregate (count)

Answer (score 0):

I made another test recently and the general process is as follows
Source (Invoices), Source (Customers), Join, Aggregate (count)

1. I create two soucres and I will link them each other by the key `SalesOrderID` later. The `source1` analogy cutomer table and the `source2`  analogy invoice table.
   [image]
2. Then I aggregate the source2 , **Group by** `SalesOrderID` and **Aggregates** with the expression `count(1)` as follows:
   [image]
   [image]
3. End, I join the two sources with the key `SalesOrderID` and this works well.
   [image]

Comment: Hi, it my be a way to work around, but every source of the dataflow is an incremental load from a SQL onpremise to a datalake and that field is part of the whole stream that sinks into a new dataset in Azure SLQ. Thats why i need to make that count() using the loaded sources.

any tips to work around this?